# not able to route through Layout component

Tags: reactjs

Please check for dashboard.js component for more details.no errors no warnings.it is getting routed but not getting rendered.while all routes are wrapped by browser router.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Card from "../../cards/card";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Axios from "axios";
import "./dashboard.css";
import IndiaTimeLine from "../../charts/indiatimeline/indiaTimeLine";
import World from '../../charts/world/world';
import Header from '../header'

export default class dashboard extends Component {
  state = {
    worldStats: {},
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTotalData();
  }

  getTotalData() {
    Axios.get("https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/all").then((res) => {
      this.setState({ worldStats: res.data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='back'>

        {/* <Header/> */}
        <Container className='cont'>
          <Row>
            <h2 className='title'>World Statistics</h2>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col lg='3'>
              <Card
                title='Active Cases'
                count={this.state.worldStats.cases}
                class='active'
              ></Card>
            </Col>
            <Col lg='3'>
              <Card
                title='Deaths'
                count={this.state.worldStats.deaths}
                class='death'
              ></Card>
            </Col>
            <Col lg='3'>
              <Card
                title='Recovered'
                count={this.state.worldStats.recovered}
                class='recovered'
              ></Card>
            </Col>
            <Col lg='3'>
              <Card
                title='Affected Countries'
                count={this.state.worldStats.affectedCountries}
                class='today'
              ></Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <h2 className='title'>Cases Today</h2>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col lg='3'>
              <Card
                title='Active Cases'
                count={this.state.worldStats.todayCases}
                class='active'
              ></Card>
            </Col>
            <Col lg='3'>
              <Card
                title='Deaths'
                count={this.state.worldStats.todayDeaths}
                class='death'
              ></Card>
            </Col>
            <Col lg='3'>
              <Card
                title='Tests'
                count={this.state.worldStats.tests}
                class='recovered'
              ></Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          
        </Container>
        <Container>
        <Row>
              <World />
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to make header global. The component should render through the Layout component.Currently, I am able to route but the Dashboard component is not getting rendered.

```
    import React from "react";
        import Header from "./header";
        import { Router, Switch, Route, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
        import Dashboard from './dashboard/dashboard';
        import India from '../india/india';


        function layout(props) {
        return (
        <div>
         <Header></Header>
         {props.children}
        </div>
        );
       }

       export default layout;

        import React from "react";
        import "./App.css";
        import Dashboard from "./components/layout/dashboard/dashboard";
        import  Layout from "./components/layout/header";
        import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route,withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
        import India from './components/india/india'
        import Header from './components/layout/header'
        import Login from "./components/Login/Login";

        function App(props) {
         console.log(props)
         return (
                 <Router>
                   <div className='App'>
                      <Switch>
                      <Route exact path='/dashboard' render={()=><Layout><Dashboard/></Layout>} />
                    <Route exact path='/india' component={India} />
                 <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
                </Switch>
             </div>
             </Router>

        );
      }
       export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: No errors, warnings? show ur dashboard file

Comment: @Panther no errors and warnings